# Run untrusted code at Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to run untrusted JavaScript code so I want to use a function as a sandbox, where the user can just run simple JavaScript.

I'm not actually whitelisted yet to use Google Cloud functions, but I have this question:

Do HTTP functions have access to my Google Cloud context?

Comment: All Javascript code for handling HTTP requests in Cloud Functions runs inside the [exported function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http).  To run the user's JS code within your HTTP function, you would need to pass the code to the server like by request body and have the HTTP function parse like by using `eval` which is extremely unsecure.  Can you provide an example of user JS code that you would want run from your HTTP function?  What do you mean by Google Cloud context?

Comment: Will be an application like "codepen" or "jsfiddle". But in my case it evaluates the user code in the server. If it has malicious code and the exported function has no other external information (is isolated) it will be no problem, because it will have no information to stole or crash. But if my google cloud credentials, for example, is exposed to this exported function it will be a problem.. In my actual architecture I use [node vm](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) to handle it..

Comment: What specific serverside capabilities do you require that clientside JS execution does not provide?

Comment: No one.. But for privacy reasons the code generated by the user A cannot be exposed to the user B that's using the code..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, you are looking to have Cloud HTTP Functions evaluate user-provided Javascript code on the server side.

By your description, the only real ways the function would be able to evaluate the user's code would be essentially using [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) or [`new Function()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).  To confirm the risks I mentioned, I created a cloud function that simply passes the POST request body to `eval`.  Without any dependencies, I could issue HTTP requests on behalf of the cloud function which could be quite bad.

Given that most useful cloud functions would have [`"@google-cloud"`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/google-cloud/0.44.2/google-cloud) as a dependency, the user could gain access to that context.  I was able to require `@google-cloud` and get all the information accessible to that object (application credentials, application information, etc.).  Having such information available to a malicious user is considerably worse that the first test.  In addition, Cloud Functions are authenticated by default, presumably by default application credentials, thus gaining all the abilities of the gcloud client library.

In the end, the **safest** way to run user-provided code on the server would be within a container.  This would essentially lock the user's code into a Linux box where the resources and networking capabilities can be entirely governed by you.  On the Google Cloud Platform, you're best means of accomplishing this would likely be using App Engine as a front-end to handle user requests and Compute Engine VMs to create and run containers for user code.  It's more complex but doesn't risk destroying your Google Cloud Platform project.

Comment: Just a note: cloud functions will have configurable permissions soon, but I agree that they are unsuitable for the OP's use-case.  Callouts alone could allow spamming or other malicious activity.